# Do LXD containers count towards Landscape Free Tier's machine count?

Tags: landscape, lxd

Landscape On-premises is free for up to 10 machines, do LXD containers on an installation of Ubuntu Server count towards this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free tier license which comes with on-premises installations currently includes both 10 full (physical machines) seats and 50 container seats. You can see on the license page (which you can access at https://your-server/account/standalone/licenses) how many you have of each type and how many of are in use.